# Problem copying all files that were copied to bin folder by sub-project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# solution, with 2 projects - `MainProject` and `SubProject`. `MainProject` references the `SubProject` project. In `SubProject`, I have a folder `RequiredStuff`, with many items including both managed and unmanaged DLLs, image files, scripts, configuration files etc.

In `SubProject`, I have made a post-build event with command `copy "$(ProjectDir)RequiredStuff\*" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"`. When I build this project, *all* the files in `RequiredStuff` are copied to the `bin` folder (instead of `bin\RequiredStuff`), which is what I wanted.

When I build the whole solution, *only some* of the files, which were originally in `RequiredStuff`, were copied. After careful examination, I figured some sort of pattern. Example:

- `FooBar.dll`: Not copied
- `FooBar_Test.dll`: Copied

How should I do to make sure all the files are copied over to `MainProject`'s bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)RequiredStuff`. Before copying you have to make sure the folder is created, with something like:

```
dir "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)RequiredStuff\" >nul 2>&1
if "%errorlevel%" neq "0" mkdir "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)RequiredStuff"
copy "$(ProjectDir)RequiredStuff\*" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)RequiredStuff\"
```

Comment: No, I was using post-build event so that it doesn't get moved to a sub-folder in `bin` directory.

Comment: I thought you wanted to copy to a sub folder (`RequiredStuff`), I obviously misunderstood.